# How to insert text from text field into alert view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uialertview

if I wanted to insert text from a text field into an alert view, wouldn't I use this code? Where the text should be, it says: . Thanks for your help!

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message: %@",textField.text delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
... message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message: %@",textField.text] ...
```